# Find the 2nd-degree polynomial that approximates with the method of the least squares the:$f(x)=\frac{1}{10}x^2-2x+10$

Tags: polynomials, approximation, orthogonal-polynomials

It is known that a rectangular set of polynomials $\phi_k(x), k=0,1,\cdots,n$ for each $x\in[a,b]$ as to a weight function $w(x)$ can be constructed with the use of the following recursive type (Gram-Schmidt process):

$\phi_0(x)=1$

$\phi_1(x)=x- a_0$, where $a_0=\frac{(x\phi_0, \phi_0)}{(\phi_0,\phi_0)}$

and

$\phi_{k+1}(x)=(x-a_k)\phi_k(x)-\beta_k\phi_{k-1}(x),   
 k=1,2,\cdots,n-1$,

where $a_k=\frac{(x\phi_k, \phi_k)}{(\phi_k,\phi_k)}$, and $b_k=\frac{(x\phi_k, \phi_{k-1})}{(\phi_{k-1},\phi_{k-1})}$.

***Using the Gram-Schmidt process above to find***: the second-degree polynomial $p_2(x)$ that approximates with the method of the least squares the 
$f(x)=\frac{1}{10}x^2-2x+10$

in points $(x_i,f_i), i=1,2,\cdots,6$

with $x_i=10+\frac{i-1}{5}$, $f_i=f(x_i)$ and $w(x)=1.$

Comment: The second degree polynomial that approximates this will be the same as you are trying to approximate.  If you want an approximation, it should be of lower degree and you need to specify the range of the approximation.

Comment: Do you mean that i can't find the second-degree polynomial? These are exactly the data given to me.

Comment: You already have a second degree polynomial.  It is in the title of the question.  Any approximation technique on three or more points should reproduce it.

Comment: My problem is how to start.How i will use this Gram-Schmidt process? Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 3):

First make a table of your data. $$\begin {array}{r|r|r} i&x_i&f(x_i)\\ \hline 1&10&0\\2&10.2&0.004\\3&10.4&0.016\\4&10.6&0.036\\5&10.8&0.064\\6&11&0.1 \end {array}$$
Then, as the instructions say, $\phi_0=1$ and $\phi_1=x-\frac {(x\phi_0,\phi_0)}{\phi_0,\phi_0}=x-\frac {(x,1)}{(1,1)}$  The terms in parentheses are sums over the products at the points.  So $(x,1)=10*1+10.2*1+\ldots 11*1=63, (1,1)=6$, which gives $\phi_1(x)=x-10.5$.   Now you need to find $\phi_2$, which will be a quadratic.
Then you can express $f(x)=a_0\phi_0+a_1\phi_1+a_2\phi_2$  You can either find the $a$'s by expanding out the right side and equating like coefficients of $x$, or use the orthogonality to write $a_i=\frac {(f(x_i),\phi_i)}{(\phi_i,\phi_i)}$